# How do I get the method body from a MemberAccessExpressionSyntax?

Tags: c#, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn and trying to build an analyzer which will go through the entire source of a method (including all sub-methods) in order to provide insight to the user.

It's unlcear to me how to step into the MemberAccessExpression (which points at the method) so that I can begin browsing the file that contains the method.

I've tried iterating over the `ChildNodes` and `ChildTokens`, I've also looked over the object in the debugger and I see no property I could use to load the class/method that the MemberAccessExpression  refers to.

After traversing the tree to find the method I'm interested in exploring, I do the following:

```
private void AnalyzeSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
{
    if (this.foundMethod)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (syntaxNode is InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpressionSyntax)
    {
        this.foundMethod = true;
        PrintNodeAndChildren(invocationExpressionSyntax);
    }

    var children = syntaxNode.ChildNodes();

    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        AnalyzeSyntaxNode(child);
    }
}

private void PrintNodeAndChildren(SyntaxNode node)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Child: {node}");

    var children = node.ChildNodes();

    if (children.Any())
    {
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            PrintNodeAndChildren(child);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access the class that contains the method, and also the body of the method itself.

In the following example, I start traversing the SyntaxTree of `Caller`, and I want to access the body of `Callee.DoSomethingElse`.  In reality, my goal is to replace `_visited = true` with `_visited = 99` in `Callee.DoSomethingElse`, however if I can just figure out how to access that part of the tree, I feel as though I can replace the node(s) myself.

#### Caller.cs

```
public class Caller
{
    private Callee _callee = new Callee();
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _callee.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

#### Callee.cs (Different project to Caller.cs)

```
public class Callee
{
    private int _visited = 0;
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        _visited = 1;
    }
}
```

This is an arbitrary, nonsensical example, but I feel as though it gets the point across.

Comment: You should consider using an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.7.2) to walk over expression trees.  It makes things so much easier.  It will also help you with replacing the constants.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - I wasn't aware of the ability to use an ExpressionVisitor to walk a [Syntax Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.syntaxtree?view=roslyn-dotnet).  It turns out that there is a type [CSharpSyntaxVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxvisitor?view=roslyn-dotnet) well suited to this, thanks for the pointer!  Now, if you can help me with the problem in the post I'll give you MORE points! ;)

Comment: [CSharpSyntaxVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxvisitor?view=roslyn-dotnet) seems to be the visitor I should use, however given I want to find a particular method and perform some operation on it, I'm not sure this type is well suited, is there another more applicable type for traversing a `SyntaxTree`?

Comment: I think that `SyntaxVisitor` is the correct class to use.  It seems to work along the same pattern as the `ExpressionVisitor`.  You should be able to overide `VisitMethodDeclaration` to locate the method you are interested in, and `VisitAssignmentExpression` to change the line you want to change.  I'd be willing to help you with an example, but setting everything up correctly seems like it could be very involved, and I've never done it before. [...]

Comment: [...]  If you had a starter project that you could share, that gets everything in the right state where I just had to implement the visitor, I would be willing to take a look.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - Thanks for the offer, I may well take you up on it.  I'm working on understanding the traversal path of `CSharpSyntaxVisitor` as my use-case is finding a method and then specifically traversing the contents (and children) of that one method.  I think a custom visitor class might be the best solution here, but I'll report back later today with my findings!

Comment: @BradleyUffner - It seems as though `VisitMethodDeclaration` and  `VisitAssignmentExpression` are disjoint enough to make linking the method declaration to the assignment expression difficult.  Am I being naive here?  How in the `VisitAssignmentExpression` call can I know that it's in the correct method?

Comment: I've been able to get a working setup in LINQPad, and am doing some testing now.

Comment: I've got something working!  I'm typing up an answer for you now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the correct class to use for this is a [`CSharpSyntaxRewriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxrewriter?view=roslyn-dotnet), a subclass of `CSharpSyntaxVisitor`, which can make it significantly easier to navigate syntax trees.

It functionally works the same way the `CSharpSyntaxVisitor`, but allows syntax nodes to be modified.

Here is my implementation of the class:

```
public class AssignmentReplacer : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private string inMethod;

    public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        inMethod = node.Identifier.ValueText;

        return base.VisitMethodDeclaration(node);
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitAssignmentExpression(AssignmentExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        if (inMethod == "DoSomethingElse")
        {
            if (node.Left is IdentifierNameSyntax name &&
               name.Identifier.Text == "_visited")
            {

                return node.Update(node.Left,
                                   node.OperatorToken,
                                   SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.TrueLiteralExpression));
            }
        }

        return base.VisitAssignmentExpression(node);
    }
}
```

As it walks the tree depth-first, it tracks its current method location from `VisitMethodDeclaration` in a private field.  It uses that in `VisitAssignmentExpression` to make sure it is in the correct method when it modifies the node.

Once it has identified an `AssignmentExpressionSyntax` node inside the correct method, it creates a modified copy of the node, with the right side changed to a new `LiteralExpression`.

You may have to add more checks around this to be sure you are modifying the correct node, but this works for your simple example data.

You can use the class like this:

```
var programText =
@"public class Callee
{
    private bool _visited = false;
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        _visited = false;
    }
}";

var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(programText);
var root = tree.GetRoot();

var visitor = new AssignmentReplacer();
var updated = visitor.Visit(root);
```

After running the visitor, `updated` will contain the modified code:

> ```
> public class Callee
> {
>     private bool _visited = true;
>     public void DoSomethingElse()
>     {
>         _visited = true;
>     }
> }
> ```

Just as a word of caution, this is the first time I've done any of this, so it may not be the most efficient, or best way to do it.

Thank you for an interesting challenge!

A fully working LINQPad example can be found [here](http://share.linqpad.net/roow5g.linq).

Comment: Whilst that works in your example, once I expand it out to the multi project example I laid out in my question, I run into the same problem.  I created a [simple project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/unh5opi7vu59vpl/Playground.zip?dl=0) to demonstrate the issue

Comment: `Visit` returns a `SyntaxNode` containing the modified code. You need to do something with that node, as the original `SyntaxNode` is immutable.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain properly.  The attached project shows that `Callee` is not a child node of `Caller` due to the projects being analysed separately.

Comment: Change the inner `if` in `AssignmentReplacer.VisitAssignmentExpression` to `if (node.Left is MemberAccessExpressionSyntax member && member.Name.Identifier.Text == "_visited")`, and your code works.

Comment: That only works because `inMethod == "DoSomethingElse"`, when I want to find the expression via `inMethod == "DoSomething"`.  The key part of my question that is unanswered is "It's unclear to me how to step into the MemberAccessExpression (which points at the method) so that I can begin browsing the file that contains the method.".  From the `Caller` project where I find the method `DoSomething` which calls `DoSomethingElse`, at that point I want to update the source of `DoSomethingElse`.

Comment: You also need to remember to clear `inMethod` when you leave the `VisitMethodDeclaration`, otherwise you get a false positive.